# Single Service Two Binding But different Behavior for Different Binding

Tags: c#, wcf

I am exploring bit more detail of WCF Instance context mode and Concurrency and get confused over managed threadID value for BasicHttpBinding and WSHttpBinding.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
 public class Service2 : IService1
    {
        int i;
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            string output = string.Format("Service2 {0} , {1} , {2}", 
                                          DateTime.Now.ToString(), 
                                          i++, 
                                   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            Console.WriteLine(output);            
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return output;
        }
}
```

Sample Test

```
public class program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2), 
                               new Uri("http://localhost:9011"), 
                               new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9009"));                                  
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), 
                                    new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), 
                                    new WSHttpBinding(), "WS");          

            Test1();
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Test2();
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Test1()
        {
            EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            ChannelFactory<IService1> client = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endPoint);
            IService1 proxy = client.CreateChannel();
            Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(cc =>
            {
                proxy.GetData(10);
            });
        }

        public static void Test2()
        {
            EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9011/WS");
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            ChannelFactory<IService1> client = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endPoint);
            IService1 proxy = client.CreateChannel();
            Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(cc =>
            {
                proxy.GetData(10);
            });
        }
     }
```

Now Problem is with ManagedThreadId.

If you look at output of Test1() then ManagedThreadId value is same for all 10.

But if you look at Test2() Then ManagedThreadId value it is different.

Why it is like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode` are essentially an abstraction layer that controls *the instance lifetime of a service object and how calls are serialised* (if any) to it and **does not** describe **threading models** to the point of whether the same thread will be used or not.

If we look at your example:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

...that's essentially setting up thread-safe; singleton service.  For single mode concurrency, all calls are queued and executed one at a time. [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489)

### Custom Thread Synchonisation Contexts

In my readings and experience, though WCF doesn't say anything about *which* thread will be used for the above attributes, WCF is compatible with different and custom *thread synchonisation contexts* though such implementations have:

> *"...nothing to do with WCF"*; Lowy, [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489)

OP:

> If you look at output of Test1() then ManagedThreadId value is same for all 10.
>
> But if you look at Test2() Then ManagedThreadId value it is different

I'd say all you are seeing there is perhaps the default service behavior under `BasicHttpBinding` is to use a custom thread pool synchoniser where calls are queued up and executed in turn on the **same thread** whereas under `WSHttpBinding` the default thread pool is used (hence why the threads are different).

### More

- [Programming WCF Services: Mastering WCF and the Azure AppFabric Service Bus Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. By the way till last few days I also got realize that WCF does not tell anything about Thread. What I understood through search online your answer is something nearer. So I accept it.